# How to handle AsyncTask onPostExecute when paused to avoid IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I appreciate the numerous postings regarding AsyncTask on a rotation change. I have the following problem when using the compatability lib and trying to dismiss a `DialogFragment` in `onPostExecute`.

I have a fragment which fires of an AsyncTask which displays a progress `DialogFragment`, then in `onPostExecute` dismisses the dialog and then potentially throws up another `DialogFragment`.

If when the progress dialog is being displayed I put the application into the background I get the following for my fragment:

1) `onPause`

2) `onSaveInstanceState`

3) `onPostExecute` in which I try to dismiss and invoke a dialog.

I get an `IllegalStateException` because I'm trying to effectively commit a transaction when the activity has saved its state and I understand this.

On a rotation I've assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that I wouldn't get an `onPostExecute` until the activity has been recreated. However, when putting the application into the background I assumed (definitely incorrectly) that the `onPostExectute` wouldn't get called while the fragment/activity was paused.

My question is, is my solution to simply detect in `onPostExecute` that the fragment/activity is paused and simply perform what I need to do in `onResume` instead? Seems somewhat ugly to me.

Thanks in advance, peter.

**Edit 1**

Need to support 2.1 and above

**Edit 2**

I have considered showing the dialog using `FragmentTransaction:add` and `FragmentTransaction:commitAllowingStateLoss`however this isn't without its problems.

Comment: My [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) on fragment transactions and activity state loss might help. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need to synchronize your task with the activity lifecycle, I believe that [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) are exactly what you need. More specifically, you should use [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) to do the job. So now instead of running an AsyncTask, you launch your loader, then wait for response in a listener. If the activity is paused, you won't get a callback, this part will be managed for you.

There is another way to handle this task: using a fragment which [retains its instance](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.html). The general idea is that you create a fragment without UI and call `setRetainInstance(true)`. It has a task which is being notified about the activity being available or not. If not, the task's thread suspends until an activity becomes available.

Comment: Thanks, need to investigate this further although feels like a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut in my case where just delaying UI tasks while paused would be the simple solution.

Comment: I'm working on a bit of the same problem right now, and I've found a new solution. Maybe it will help you too. Check it out, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Malcolm can you give link to any documentation which says `If the activity is paused, you won't get a callback`? I couldn't find it anywhere in the `loaders` documentation.

Comment: @zack It isn't stated in the documentation explicitly as far as I know, but I looked in the source code, and that's how it behaves. I would still check if the app is resumed, though.

Answer (score 8):

Another way of achieving what you require is to implement the PauseHandler class that I documented [**in this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8040280/844882).

Then in your onPostExecute method call sendMessage() to post your message into the handler.

When your application resumes the action will be handled.

Answer (score 3):

Rather then using BroadcastReceiver, I prefer using bus libraries like guava, otto or eventbus. Their performance is much better then the broadcast receiver implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution for this problem without any major workaround:
The basic idea how to maintain a progressdialog and a asynctask is described in this [blogentry](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/) (of course I used the AsyncTaskComplex-Version). All credits go to the author of this blogentry, I only added a tiny thing:

Obviously I'm not using showDialog() anymore. Instead I stick with DialogFragments.

The second tweak is the importent one and also solves the problem with the IllegalStateException:

Instead of only telling the asynctask in onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() that there is no more activity I also do it in onPause(). And instead of only telling the asynctask in onCreate() that there is a new activity I also do it in onResume().

And there you go, your AsyncTask will not try to inform your activity about his finish causing an IllegalStateException when the activity is not visible.

If you would like to see more code instead of words, leave a comment.

**/edit:**
Sourcecode to show my solution, which I think is a pretty decent one :)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private MyTask mTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editaccount);

    Object retained = getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
    if ( retained instanceof NewContactFolderIdTask ) {
        mTask = (MyTask) retained;
        mTask.setActivity(this);
    }

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mTask != null) {
        mTask.setActivity(null);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
    if(mTask != null) {
        mTask.setActivity(null);
        return mTask;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(mTask != null) {
        mTask.setActivity(this);
    }
    loadValues(); // or refreshListView or whatever you need to do
    super.onResume();
}

public void onTaskCompleted() {
    loadValues();  // or refreshListView or whatever you need to do
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = (DialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PROGRESS_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
    if(dialogFragment != null) {
        dialogFragment.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in Action Bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OXClient.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            mTask = new MyTask(this);
            mTask.execute();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class NewContactFolderIdTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Integer, Bundle> {
    private MyActivity mActivity;
    private boolean mCompleted;

    private NewContactFolderIdTask(MyActivity pActivity) {
        this.mActivity = pActivity;
    }

    public void setActivity(MyActivity pActivity) {
        this.mActivity = pActivity;
        if(mCompleted) {
            notifiyActivityTaskCompleted();
        }
    }

    private void notifiyActivityTaskCompleted() {
        if(mActivity != null) {
            mActivity.onTaskCompleted();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Bundle doInBackground(Boolean... pBoolean) {
        // Do your stuff, return result
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), PROGRESS_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bundle pResult) {
        mCompleted = true;
        notifiyActivityTaskCompleted();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, the above is fine however if you put the application into the background before you get your onPostExecute I would still expect the dialogFragment to be dimissed at which point you'll see an illegalStateException unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm also getting a IllegalStateException when my asyncTask finishs while the activity/application is in the background. Never tried that befor :/

Comment: Sorry for not reading your questions carefully, totally overred the "put in background" part :/

Comment: I solved the problem, at least my local tests were all positive. As I already said: If you would like to see more code, just leave a comment.

Comment: Definitely be interested to see what you did. At the moment I'm considering either AsyncTaskLoader or simply delaying `onPostExecute` functionality until `onResume`

Comment: Sourcecode added. I think the AsyncTaskLoader is, as you said, a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nutt and also a pseudo fragment wihtout UI, srsly? Just don't let the AsyncTask call your activity while it is in the background and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I need to test this but I'm still a little confused. I'm getting in `onPause` you set your async task's activity to null? (code missing). Still don't see though what stops you getting `onPostExecute` after `onPause` or why it would come in after `onResume`.

Comment: I added the onPause() implementation and did further tests: My onPostExecute is NOT called when I press the "HOME"-Button?!?

Comment: OK, Thanks, yep can now see how it works. Although I don't see why your onPostExecute can't get called after onPause but anyway its onTaskCompleted functionality won't get processed until onResume after setting the activity.

Answer (score 2):

On [How to handle Handler messages when activity/fragment is paused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040280/how-to-handle-handler-messages-when-activity-fragment-is-paused) I offer another approach using a BroadcastReceiver.

I consider it cleaner more elegant and it offers the advantages that you can invoke code on your base fragment from everywhere within your app and by using sticky broadcasts your invocation can be "remembered" and executed after your fragment resumes.