# Keeping Messenger Alive between Service and Activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I have an Activity that binds to a `Service` and communicates through `Messenger`s and `Handler`s.  When the user clicks on a menu item, it brings a new Activity up where they can select something from an `ExpandableListView`.  After the selection has been made, I call `finish()` on that Activity and the `MainActivity` is brought back.  The `MainActivity` stays bound during the process, because I call my unbind in its `onDestroy()`.  I loose my `Service` to Client Incoming `Handler`.  It's a `Messenger` I created like this:

```
//Target to allow service to send message to InccomingHandler
final Messenger serviceIncomingHandler = new Messenger(new MessageHandler(this));

/**
 * Message Handling from Service
 */ 
private static class MessageHandler extends Handler {

    private final WeakReference<RoomListActivity> mTarget;

    public MessageHandler(RoomListActivity target) {
        mTarget = new WeakReference<RoomListActivity>(target);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        RoomListActivity target = mTarget.get();
        switch (msg.what) {
            //Fancy stuff here...
        }
    }
}
```

I register the Client's `Messenger` with the `Service` by sending the `Service` a `Message` Object with `msg.replyTo = serviceIncomingHandler;`  On the `Service` side, I publish that as the `Messenger` to use for the Client.

I saw something where a Message Queue was used, but if I add extra methods to my `MessageHandler` Class, I loose the ability to create a `Messenger` from it, and I have no idea how to register a Client's Incoming `Handler` to a `Service` without sending a `Message` to the `Service` and setting the `msg.replyTo` field.

The problem is the `Messenger` gets GC'd when the `ExpandableListView Activity` starts.  I need this to stay alive, because chat messages are being sent back and forth, and I'd like to keep the history of the chat Messages available to re-populate the original `ListView`.  The history is still in an Array when the Activity is resumed, but I can't store messages that are being sent while the `ExpandableListView Activity` is the foreground because my Messenger gets killed.

Is there a way to keep the Messenger alive, or a better approach than what I am using currently?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why is the `Messenger` getting GC'd when the `ListViewActivity` starts? Aren't are you keeping a reference to this object somewhere? This doesn't sound right.

Comment: @DavidWasser Because the `ListViewActivity` is a new `Activity`, I'm assuming?  If it doesn't have any messages in queue, and a new `Activity` is started, I'm guessing VM says we're done with that allocation...?

Comment: Where are you keeping the reference to `Messenger`? In which Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work by implementing the following answer to my situation.  Hopefully this will help some other people as well.
[Paused Handler Abstract Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122789/1366913)

Thanks to @quickdrawmcgraw