# Best way to Handle FragmentTransaction in AsyncTask.onPostExecute after onDestroy is called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-activity

In my application, I always need to execute some stuff at the first time the app is open. When user opens it, the app shows a dialog with a progressbar, while executes an `AsyncTask` on background, and after (on `onPostExecute()`) i need to commit a `Fragment`.

So, in my Main `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, I have:

```
public class InitialActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_initial);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) //Executes just at the firstTime
        {
            //ApplicationStarter -> It manages all execution to start my app, executes asynctask, shows dialogs..
            ApplicationStarter starter = new ApplicationStarter(this) {

                @Override
                public void afterFinish() {
                    //It Executes at onPostExecute when doInBackground() finishes
                    ItensFragment itensfrag = new ItensFragment();
                    frag.setTargetFragment(itensfrag , 0);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, itensfrag);
                    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();   

                }
            };
            starter.start();
        }
    }
}
```

So, everything goes Ok, but the app crashes if user rotates the device or after `onDestroy()` method is called. The following exception is launched:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

at `ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();`

I searched around and I found [on this post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) that it isn't a good practice to perform a `Fragment` transiction inside asynchronous callback methods like i am trying to do.
[And i saw this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122789/2327056) too, that maybe i could adapt to my case. But before that, i would like to know if anyone has a better way or suggestion for what i'm trying to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: happens bcoz when orientation changes your activity is destroyed and recreated. Asynctask as the name suggests is asynchronous

Comment: you could check this blog if it helps. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How @Raghunandan suggested, i followed [this post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) and everything worked fine. The big difference is that now i call my ApplicationStarter on `onCreate` of my Fragment which is set to `setRetainInstance(true)`. The InitialActivity has an instance of `ItensFragment`. The code in my `InitialActivity`'s `onCreate()` is:

```
public class InitialActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private ItensFragment itensfrag;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicial);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    itensfrag= (ItensFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("itensfrag");
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        if (itensfrag== null) {
            itensfrag= new ItensFragment();
          fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.simple_fragment, itensfrag, "itensfrag").commit();
        }
    }
}
}
```