# How to perform background operations in Android that update the UI properly using Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-fragmentactivity

I couldn't find any solution to this problem that satisfies all my requirements.

In my application I use `AsyncTasks` to perform some operations like saving data to a memory or reading data from a database. I create a progress dialog in `onPreExecute`, update a progress value in `onProgressUpdate` and dismiss the dialog in `onPostExecute`.

Recently I switched to the Fragment API (I use the Support Library to target older versions of Android), meaning that my activities subclass `FragmentActivity` and dialogs subclass `DialogFragment`.

Switching to the Fragment API caused a well-known problem - sometimes I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

This happens, for instance, when a user starts a background operation (a progress dialog appears), uses the home button to minimize the application and the operation finishes when the activity is in background. The application then tries to dismiss the dialog and this fails since the state of the activity was saved.

I understand the issue. It can be fixed by ensuring that changes to the UI are postponed until the activity is resumed as described in this post: [How to handle Handler messages when activity/fragment is paused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040280/how-to-handle-handler-messages-when-activity-fragment-is-paused).

However, this solution leads to another problem. What if the operation finishes when the activity is in background and later the activity is killed by Android? When a user navigates back to the application, it restores its state that was saved in `onSaveInstanceState`. Therefore, the progress dialog is still visible with the same progress value as when the activity was put into background. A message that should dismiss it, was never processed and it was lost when the activity was killed.

What is the correct solution that handles all the described issues properly? How to allow for changing the UI when the activity is in background or, at least, allow for postponing UI changes and ensuring they won't be lost in case the activity is killed by Android? The solution must allow for tracking progress of a background task.

Comment: If the `DialogFragment` is restored upon `Fragment` reinstantiation, then just perform a check on whether the operation is still running, and dismiss the `DialogFragment` if not. If you aren't persisting your tasks, then it won't be running in any case after a process restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only sure-fire way to avoid the situation you've described is to persist the results to some sort of storage. You could start a service to do the long-running task, and have it write the results to a database, and also send a local broadcast when complete.

If the activity happens to be in the foreground, it will receive the broadcast and update its state to know that the process has finished, and could remove the information about the task 
from whatever persistent storage mechanism you use.

If the activity is in the background, the service will finish, send the broadcast, and persist the results. The next time the activity comes to the foreground, it should check this persistent storage and see if there's an unresolved task status, and update its state to match.

So, an example rundown might be (let's use "Uploading a Photo" as the task):

1. User clicks a button to start an image upload
2. Activity starts a service to upload the image to a remote service
3. Activity registers a `LocalBroadcastManager` for some broadcast event that you define (e.g. `com.mypackage.ACTION_PHOTO_UPlOADED`)
4. Service persists some information about the task (e.g. SharedPreferences.putBoolean("TASK_PHOTO_UPLOADED", false)
5. Activity shows some sort of loading UI while the service processes the upload task
6. User presses home and sends the app into stopped state
7. Activity unregisters the local broadcast manager
8. The service finishes uploading the image
9. The service sends a local broadcast (`com.mypackage.ACTION_PHOTO_UPlOADED`) which is unused because the Activity is no longer listening
10. The service updates the persisted information (`SharedPreferences.putBoolean("TASK_PHOTO_UPLOADED", true)`)
11. Android kills off the Activity, saving its state
12. User later returns to the Activity
13. Activity checks in `onResume()` with the service to see if there's an unhandled task result (`if (SharedPreferences.has("TASK_PHOTO_UPLOADED"))`), then checks to see if it should updated the state.
14. If the photo upload key is there, and is true, Activity removes the dialog fragment and clears the `TASK_PHOTO_UPLOADED` key from SharedPreferences.
     If the photo upload key is there, and is false, Activity registers a local broadcast manager to wait for the event to complete

Comment: Although you describe it in terms of `Service` and `LocalBroadcastManager` instead of `AsyncTask`, the same idea can be used here. However, using `SharedPreferences` to keep an information whether a dialog should be dismissed next time an activity is created/resumed seems to be using a cannon to kill a fly. I wonder there's any simpler and more elegant solution.

Comment: SharedPreferences (like Service and LocalBroadcastManager) were just suggested implementations. You will need *some* sort of persistent storage -- SharedPreferences was the easiest to show, although you could use a database (now *that's* cannon to fly). Service can be substituted with an AsyncTask (although I'd highly recommend to use a Service instead as you don't have to worry about managing it with the Activity lifecycle) and LocalBroadcastManager could be replaced with an Event Bus or similar pattern.

Comment: +1 A `Service` is the way to go if you actually want to have the operation completed, even in the case of it being terminated because  of the process being killed. Otherwise, you might as well dismiss the `ProgressDialog` whenever the application is restored after being killed, as the operation would be not be running in any case, @maral. Alternatively, you might be interested in using some third-party library that will handle persistence of your tasks, such as [Tape](http://square.github.io/tape/) or [Priority Job Queue](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue).

Comment: Note that the important part here is persisting the _task_ (which would be accomplished by using a `Service`), not it's status or result, as otherwise the issue in the question doesn't apply. @maral, if you can provide a method to query the state of the operation, then that would be sufficient to determine if the `DialogFragment` needs to be dismissed upon `Fragment` reinstantiation. If you use the task queuing libraries I mentioned, they should provide this functionality inherently.

Answer (score -1):

- **Your Question was lengthy without any code sample, ill try to come up with my best answer, I have made a   project just for you on how you
  should use `onSaveinstance` state in android which will solve all the
  possible problems**
- I have written an explanation essay below that will clear all your doubts

---

In android Life-Cycle and dealing with [***Fragments***](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)

- `Activity` has the `container` for the `fragments`
- Mount the first fragment from the `oncreate` of `Activity`
- When we are using fragments to add replace etc. we need to use android `fragment` reference instead of `classreference`
- Keep the fragments in the `backstack` every time we mount the fragment to the container
- In the project we can observe that we are collecting all the states of widgets on `onpause()` and stored in a local variable and using this local variable, then pass this local variable into `onSaveInstance()` event access these tags in `onActivityCreatd()` are set to the view objects. We use this process because localvariables are holded in the class but view objects are `null` in `onSaveInstance`. This perticular observation is very important observed in `Activity`-`FragmentOne`-`FragmentTwo`-`FragmentOne`-`OrientationChange`-`OrientationChange`
- Android `static objects` are able to retain thae state `onOrientation change` but `dynamic Objects` has to be resetted `onOrientation` change with the value using localvariables as explained above
- If we are using the dynamic fragments we have the create the dynamic objects in `OnActivityCreated()` event before using the `saveInstanceState` to restore the dynamic objects
- The fragment is added to the backstack on the `onPause` event
- If the screen navigation is `Activity`-`FragmentOne`-`FragmentTwo`-`FragmentOne`-`FragmentTwo` then on press of the back button navigation works as `FragmentTwo`-`FragmentOne`-`FragmentTwo`-`FragmentOne`-`Activity`, thus we can clearly observe our path is being kept in track by the android backstack
- If the path is `Activity`-`FragmentOne` and change the orientation for the first time then the events fired are as follows 
  `MainActivity-onCreate`-
  `FragmentOne-onAttach`-
  `FragmentOne-onCreate`-
  `FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
  `FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
  `FragmentOne-onStart`-
  `FragmentOne-onResume`
- If the path is `Activity`-`FragmentOne`-`orientationchange` and change the orientation for the first time then the events fired are as follows

`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`

- If the path is `Activity`-`FragmentOne`-`orientationchange`-`orientationchange` and change the orientation for the first time then the events fired are as follows

`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`

- If the path is `Activity`-`FragmentOne`-`orientationchange`-`orientationchange`-`FragmentTwo` and change the orientation for the first time then the events fired are as follows

`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentTwo-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`

- If the path is `Activity`-`FragmentOne`-`orientationchange`-`orientationchange`-`FragmentTwo`-`orientationchange` and change the orientation for the first time then the events fired are as follows

`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentOne-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentTwo-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`-
`FragmentOne-onPause`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onSaveInstanceState`-
`FragmentOne-onStop`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`FragmentOne-onDestroy`-
`FragmentOne-onDetach`-
`MainActivity-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onAttach`-
`FragmentOne-onCreate`-
`FragmentOne-onCreateView`-
`FragmentTwo-onActivityCreated`-
`FragmentOne-onStart`-
`FragmentOne-onResume`

---

**Summarising**::

- Now remember `onPause` Event is always is fired just before closing a fragment store the values that you want to preserve `onOrientation`, when `phonecall` comes, any other scenarios
- Next `onSaveInstanceState` will be executed so use those local variables to set here to set data in `bundle`
- Next the activity will be pushed to `backstack` your data will not be lost on clicking home button
- So when `onActivityCreated` get the data from `bundle' and store it back to your`views`
- Also remember android always completes the full `lifecycle` when destroying the fragment, if it is sent to `backstack` fragment wont be destroyed(when you press home button) android destroys only when it needs more space from `backstack` and it happens automatically

---

**Let me know if you need any more information**

Comment: This answer doesn't address my question. I don't have a problem with orientation change, using `onSaveInstanceState()` or activity lifecycle. Look at the last paragraph: I ask how to ensure that a state (UI) of a `FragmentActivity` is updated (or will be updated next time a user navigates to it) if `AsyncTask` finishes when the activity is in background.

Comment: @ maral .... Ok .... i think i couldn't analyze your question.... Still the way i have mentioned how to handle the events is the right way to do this! ......`Scenario-1:` ... Navigating to next activity to be placed in `onPostExecute` so that navigation wont happen until `AsyncTask` things are completed .....`Scenario-2:` ...If you are dealing with Database, you can add it in a `Transaction`..... in one of the answers `kcoppock` also describes a way to handle this scenario in a right way. ! .....Hope that it helps