# Showing dialogs in async callbacks on Android 4+

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous, dialog

I'm look for *the* proper way of creating and showing dialogs in async callbacks.

I have read this blog post: [fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) and this Stack Overflow answer: [PauseHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122789/1262063)

However, I don't want to record activities lifecycle state. I just feel that if done correctly this should be handled for you. It seems that when the blog post and SO answer above was written (2011), this wasn't the case. You had to know the state of the Activity yourself.

How is it now, targeting only 4.0 and above, can this be done with any pattern so that you do not have to record lifecycle state?

Thanks & Best regards!