# Proper way of dismissing DialogFragment while application is in background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I started using DialogFragment, because they are working nicely through orientation changes, and stuff. But there is nasty problem I encountered.

I have `AsyncTask` that shows progress DialogFragment and dismisses it `onPostExecute`. Everything works fine, except when `onPostExecute` happens while application is in background (after pressing Home button, for example). Then I got this error on DialogFragment dismissing - "`Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`". Doh. Regular dialogs works just fine. But not FragmentDialog.

So I wonder, what is the proper way of dismissing DialogFragment while application is in background? I haven't really worked with Fragments a lot, so I think that I'm just missing something.

Comment: see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992496/how-to-handle-asynctask-onpostexecute-when-paused-to-avoid-illegalstateexception) for nice solution using a paused handler

Answer (score 168, accepted):

`DialogFragment` has a method called `dismissAllowingStateLoss()`

Comment: This only works if you use: [`show(FragmentManager, tag)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String)), but not when using [`show(FragmentTransaction, tag)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentTransaction,%20java.lang.String)) because `popBackStack` in `dismissInternal` calls `enqueueAction(..., allowStateLoss=false)` even though we asked for allowing state loss. And it does this in both framework and support versions.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I did `(df == dialogFragment)`:

Make sure that you call the dialog this way:

```
df.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogFragment_FLAG");
```

When you want to dismis the dialog make this check:

```
if (df.isResumed()){
  df.dismiss();
}
return;
```

Make sure that you have the following in the onResume() method of your fragment (not df)

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
  Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DialogFragment_FLAG");
  if (f != null) {
    DialogFragment df = (DialogFragment) f;
    df.dismiss();
  }
  super.onResume();
}
```

This way, the dialog will be dismissed if it's visible.. if not visible the dialog is going to be dismisded next the fragment becomes visible (onResume)...

Comment: This always dismisses the fragment when the user comes back, what if they didn't read the dialog yet, just left the app right after it is shown?

Comment: ```dismiss()``` already removes the dialog fragment internally. Source code: ```getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); ft.remove(this);```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I had to do to achieve what you want:
I have a Fragment activity on which i was showing a dialog fragment named `fragment_RedemptionPayment` which is globally declared at the top. The following code dismisses the `DialogFragment` if it was showing before the activity goes in background and comes back in foreground.

```
     @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();        
            if(fragment_RedemptionPayment.isVisible()){
                fragment_RedemptionPayment.dismiss();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another new way of checking the state before calling dismiss is this:

```
if(!dialog.isStateSaved){
    dialog.dismiss()
} else {
    //Change the UI to suit your functionality
}
```

In this way its is checked that state is saved or not, basically on pause and `onSaveInstanceState` has been called.

For Java you can use `isStateSaved()`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that might work is setting `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)` in your dialogfragment, but that's not the prettiest of fixes.

Sometimes I have noticed that I have to queue up my dialog actions to let the framework restore the state first. If you can get hold of the current Looper `(Activity.getMainLooper())` and wrap that in a Handler you could try passing your dismissal to the back of the queue by posting a runnable on that queue.

I often end up using a separate fragment that it `retaininstance(true)` that has a `ResultReceiver`. So i pass on that result receiver to my jobs and handle callbacks in its onReceive (often as a router for other receivers). But that might be a bit more work than it is worth if you are using async tasks.